# Merging many lists of different XTS objects in R

Tags: r, merge, xts

I have 3 lists of large XTS objects: "SMA"; "L", "Marubozu". Quick look how it looks:

```
> names(Marubozu)
 [1] "TSLA"  "AAPL"  "NTES"  "GOOGL" "ASML"  "GOOG"  "NFLX"  "ADBE"  "AMZN"  "MSFT"  "ADI"   "FB"   
> names(SMA)
 [1] "TSLA"  "AAPL"  "NTES"  "GOOGL" "ASML"  "GOOG"  "NFLX"  "ADBE"  "AMZN"  "MSFT"  "ADI"   "FB"   
> names(L)
 [1] "TSLA"  "AAPL"  "NTES"  "GOOGL" "ASML"  "GOOG"  "NFLX"  "ADBE"  "AMZN"  "MSFT"  "ADI"   "FB"

> head(Marubozu$AAPL, n = 2)
           WhiteMarubozu BlackMarubozu
2000-01-03         FALSE         FALSE
2000-01-04         FALSE         FALSE
> head(SMA$AAPL, n = 2)
           UpTrend NoTrend DownTrend Trend
2000-01-03      NA      NA        NA    NA
2000-01-04      NA      NA        NA    NA
> head(L$AAPL, n =2)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2000-01-03  0.936384  1.004464 0.907924   0.999442   535796800      0.856887
2000-01-04  0.966518  0.987723 0.903460   0.915179   512377600      0.784643
```

I want to merge corresponding XTS objects in that lists so that it creates one big lig list. For example, the output for New_List$AAPL would be:

```
AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted WhiteMarubozu BlackMarubozu UpTrend NoTrend DownTrend Trend
2000-01-03  0.936384  1.004464 0.907924   0.999442   535796800      0.856887             0             0      NA      NA        NA    NA
2000-01-04  0.966518  0.987723 0.903460   0.915179   512377600      0.784643             0             0      NA      NA        NA    NA
```

I tried to create a list of lists and merging it, but it didnt work. Here you can see:

```
#That works for a single ticker AAPL      
full <- merge.xts(L$AAPL, Marubozu$AAPL, SMA$AAPL)

#This doesn't work
out3 <- Map(function(x) {full$x <- merge.xts(lista[[1]]$x, lista[[2]]$x)}, lista)
```

I guess it is just some simple 2-lines thing but can't really find the solution, thanks for any responses!

Comment: What is `lista` here?.  I assume that your lists are `Marubozu`, `SMA` and `L` ?  In the `Map` code, the `x` is the element of `lista`.  Therefore, `lista[[1]]$x` wouldn't work

Comment: If you want to merge the corresponding elements of 'L', 'Marubozu' and 'SMA', the code would be `Map(merge.xts, L, Marubozu, SMA)` (based on the code that works for a single ticker- and assuming that all the tickers are in the same order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small function `u()` that binds the `xts`-index to an `xts` object and converts to `'data.frame'`.

```
u <- function(x) cbind.data.frame(index=index(x), unclass(x))
```

To test it, we create some data using `sample_matrix` which comes with `xts`. We split first two and last two columns into two separate `xts` objects with same index.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

S1 <- as.xts(sample_matrix[,1:2])  ##
S2 <- as.xts(sample_matrix[,3:4])
```

Now we may easily apply `merge` and create a new `xts` object out of it.

```
res <- merge(u(S1), u(S2)) |>
  (\(x) xts(x[-1], x$index, descr='my new xts object'))()

class(res)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"

stopifnot(all.equal(res, sample.xts))  ## proof
```

Comment: Works! It's definitely longer than the Akrun's one, but it's good to learn new stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We could do this with `Map` - as the `list` of `xts` elements have the same tickers in the same order, just use `Map` instead of creating a `list` of `list`s

```
library(xts)
out <- Map(merge.xts, L, Marubozu, SMA)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Actually I was trying to do the same thing, but in the wrong way. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TechLuk I thought so.  You were wrapping in a `list` and trying to extract the components.  With that code, it would be `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]`, `x[[3]]`

Comment: Exactly. I've understood that I should read more about Map function and indexing aswell